# Finding the width of the thumb of horizontal scrollbar in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating a book project where if audio button is clicked the book will be read. As the book is being read I am highlighting the corresponding word. Now when there is a long text a horizontal scrollbar appears as the `overflow-x: scroll;` property is set.
[image]

Now, if the visible part of the screen is read i need to move the thumb of the scrollbar/slide to the next part of the content. Here comes the problem. Lets say the div width is `650px` and the scrolling width is `1500px`. If contents of `650px` are read, I need to show the contents of next `650px`. If I `scrollLeft: 650px` a part of the next `650px` of content will be missing as I scrolled too much. So, I have to find the width of the thumb too. So the part I will require to `scrollLeft` will be `650 - thumb's width`. How do I find thumb's width?  Or is there any alternate way I can do this?

Comment: any help anyone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach to solve what you're asking.

#### Setup

On pageload, it will set the paragraph to one line, due to `white-space: nowrap;` in CSS.

Two variables will be assigned to elements in the DOM; `button` and `content`.

#### Slide to right

After that, when clicking the button (it can be any trigger), the container where everything is in will `scrollLeft` the `scrollWidth` of content (which is around `5000px` in this case) divided by 3. In JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += (content.scrollWidth / 3);
```

Play around with your needs, but this is a basic example. You can read more about [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) and [scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth) at MDN.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('moveButton');
const content = document.getElementById('text');

button.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += (content.scrollWidth / 3);
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#text {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p id="text">Morbi eros ligula, hendrerit in imperdiet ac, porta ut ex. Suspendisse fringilla gravida turpis venenatis pharetra. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc facilisis dapibus tristique. Nunc id facilisis est, nec gravida diam. Duis feugiat quam ac velit consequat,
    vel pharetra odio convallis. Donec tempor, mi id sollicitudin lacinia, nunc augue cursus lacus, at pretium nisi quam non risus. Cras faucibus enim tellus, quis sollicitudin elit commodo nec. Nam ornare auctor lectus quis porttitor. Vivamus facilisis
    nisl id libero gravida, eget ornare erat mattis. Ut auctor commodo sollicitudin. Mauris lectus purus, commodo sit amet nunc non, lobortis feugiat metus. Fusce non aliquet velit. Etiam congue purus at quam pharetra porta. Etiam nec magna at elit ullamcorper
    varius ut vitae metus.</p>
</div>

<button id="moveButton" type="button">Move to right</button>
```

Comment: thanks man for responding. But if I press the first time , "_venenatis pharetra. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc facilisis dapibus tristique. Nunc id facilisis est, nec gravida diam. Duis feugiat quam ac velit consequat, vel pharetra_" all those texts viewers miss.

Comment: But if I divide scrollWidth by clientWidth, take the ceiling value and add 1 to this users can view everything and without any miss. Here [link](https://codepen.io/theAlphaActual/pen/RwarbmY)

Comment: @HassanNomani Like I said: Play around with your needs.

Comment: Actually it helped me to solve the problem. Marking as the correct answer. Thanks mate!